# CSS border-radius on iFrame embedding google maps, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a button on my site, on clicking it will show/hide a google map div (embedded using iframe). It is working fine except the border-radius is working only during jquery animate. Once the animation is done, the iframe becomes square.

[I have setup a jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/N3mFg/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="layer-2">
    <span id="moreInfo">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d12242.306455925878!2d-75.12138282383809!3d39.90611059880662!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x3e48fdca1ebac4d0!2sWalt+Whitman+Bridge!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1395728987250" width="300" height="200" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
    </span>
</div>
<button>Show</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function () {
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        if(parseInt($("#moreInfo").css("opacity"))) {
            $("button").text("Show");
            $("#moreInfo").css({opacity:1,top:0,height:200,display:'inline'});
            $("#moreInfo").animate({opacity: 0,top: 100,height: 100}, 100, function () {$("#moreInfo").hide();});
        } else {
            $("button").text("Hide");
            $("#moreInfo").css({opacity:0,top:100,height:100,display:'inline'});
            $("#moreInfo").show();
            $("#moreInfo").animate({opacity: 1,top: 0,height: 200}, 100);
        }
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#moreInfo {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
#layer-2 {
    height: 200px;
}
body {
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

> Note: Please don't mark this duplicate, I have gone through a number of stack overflow answers, but none of them helped. Also please don't suggest for any other google maps api integration, I need to use the iFrame implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does work, you need to use `overflow: hidden;` for the `span` element as your `iframe` overflows out of the `span` element, and since you don't have `border-radius` applied on the iframe, it renders as a rectangle block...

```
#moreInfo {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: blue;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/N3mFg/1/)</kbd>

---

If you don't want to use `overflow: hidden;` for the parent, than use the `border-radius` for the `iframe` as well... and get rid of `blue` *background color*...

```
#moreInfo iframe {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/N3mFg/2/)</kbd> *(As [you commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627311/css-border-radius-on-iframe-embedding-google-maps-not-working/22627372#comment34458335_22627372), fails on Chrome, will look into it soon)*

Comment: I am ok with `overflow`. I had tried the second method myself, but its not working on chrome and safari

Answer (score 0):

It would be work if add border-radius to .gm-style

```
.gm-style{

        -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
        -moz-border-radius: 50%;
        border-radius: 50%;
    }
```

It's working for me