# CSS - radius on embedded iframe not working

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to embed an iframe (Blogger) in a **section** on my [website](http://ziga-lausegger.netau.net/strani/dnevnik.php) and make its corners round. I am using CSS and have tried to do it using `overflow: hidden;` like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627311/css-border-radius-on-iframe-embedding-google-maps-not-working). For some strange reason mine isn't working - check the image.

[image]

CSS:

```
section iframe.dnevnik{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 770px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}   

section.dnevnik {
    margin-top: 83px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: s10;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #EFEFEF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

implementation in HTML:

```
<section class="dnevnik">
  <iframe class="dnevnik" src ="http://ziga-lausegger.blogspot.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</section>
```

Can anyone tell me why isn't overflow working if i use it on a parrent element according to iframe?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I know what you mean. http://jsfiddle.net/kkzpp6rm/ It looks fine to me. What is the expected result?

Comment: @redditor I believe if you were to increase the border radius by a lot, the iframe ends up sticking out and the `overflow: hidden;` has no effect.

Comment: Hmmm I am a bit confused, but can you see the overflow happening on the link to my web page? I allso uploaded a pic.

Comment: I believe overflow won't work on an iframe. To be honest, I'm not sure why but the only thing I can think of in achieving this is if you created an image(or styled elements) for the rounded corners and placed it on top of each corner while making its z-index above the iframe's.

Comment: Tried that and isn't working :)

Comment: Are you searching for something like http://prntscr.com/5b80ao? (highlighted added CSS)

Comment: Not really. I want to achieve something like this: http://shrani.si/f/S/1G/4JzIK2Jp/brane-qr1.png

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was that you were applying the `border-radius: 10px;` to the `<section>` instead of the `<iframe>`.  You code *should* look like this:

```css
section iframe.dnevnik{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 770px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}   

iframe.dnevnik {
    margin-top: 83px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: s10;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #EFEFEF;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="dnevnik">
  <iframe class="dnevnik" src ="http://ziga-lausegger.blogspot.com/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</section>
```

Simply change `section.dnevnik` to `iframe.dnevnik`.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't notice the difference between your and my code.

Comment: change `section.dnevnik` to `iframe.dnevnik`.

Comment: The iframe DOES have a border-radius in my example